# How to save authUser object from middleware into request [fastify]

Tags: fastify

I wanted to save authUser object into fastify request before it comes into handler.

I did it like this in router.

```js
fastify.route({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/user',
        preHandler: [
            checkValidRequest,
            checkValidUser
        ],
        handler: controllers.getAllUsers
    })
```

But It always comes into handler before it's getting it from db. so, that means I can't run async function into middleware in fastify?

Comment: Could you add the code of your prehandler?

Comment: you can refer to the repo from [here](https://github.com/hmake98/fastify-typescript).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [documented](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Hooks/#respond-to-a-request-from-a-hook):

> It is important to not mix callbacks and async/Promise, otherwise the hook chain will be executed twice.

And it is your case